# install cuda module fails to find cuda driver library

Tags: haskell, cuda, gpu, nvidia

I'm trying to install Manuel Chakravarty's accelerate module, but having some trouble with the cuda dependency.

I have installed both the CUDA developer driver and the CUDA toolkit from nvidia. To wit:

```
ludflu@beefy ~/Downloads $ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2011 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Thu_Jan_12_14:41:45_PST_2012
Cuda compilation tools, release 4.1, V0.2.1221
```

installing the cuda cabal module fails like this:

```
cabal  install cuda
Resolving dependencies...
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( /tmp/cuda-0.4.1.07892/cuda-0.4.1.0/Setup.hs, /tmp/cuda-0.4.1.07892/cuda-0.4.1.0/dist/setup/Main.o )
Linking /tmp/cuda-0.4.1.07892/cuda-0.4.1.0/dist/setup/setup ...
Configuring cuda-0.4.1.0...
...
checking for library containing cuDriverGetVersion... no
configure: error: could not find CUDA driver library
********************************************************************************

The configuration process failed to locate your CUDA installation. Ensure that
you have installed the driver and developer toolkit, available from:

  http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads

Then make sure that "nvcc" is available in your PATH, or set the appropriate
directories with --extra-include-dirs and --extra-lib-dirs.

********************************************************************************
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
cuda-0.4.1.0 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

So I tried specifying the path:

```
cabal --extra-include-dirs=/usr/local/cuda/include --extra-lib-dirs=/usr/local/cuda/lib install cuda
```

But that fails the same way.

Any suggestions on what I should try next?

Comment: You could try reading the error messages a little more closely: "configure: error: could not find CUDA driver library". That probably means you don't have a correct NVIDIA *driver* installation.

Comment: Actually, I installed both the driver and the toolkit. (As mentioned in the 2nd line of my question.) Are you saying the driver is different from the "developer driver"?

Comment: No, I am not. But that looks like the source of your problem. The driver library ships in the driver package. Are you sure the driver installed correctly? You should be able to find libcuda.so in /usr/lib or /usr/lib64, depending on what flavour of linux and architecture you are using, or libcuda.dylib in /usr/local/cuda/lib

Comment: Have you succesfully tried some native Cuda stuff yet? I remember I initially had some problems with that when I first set nvcc up, but when it worked the cabal installation of CUDA and Accelerate then went without any problems.

Comment: leftaroundabout - that turned out to me good advice. I switched to my MacBook, which was exhibiting the same error. I got a CUDA hello world program working, and now cuda/accelerate installs fine. (LD_LIBRARY_PATH wasn't set correctly.) I don't know what the issue was on my workstation, but it was probably something similar. I'll update with an answer when I get it working on my workstation.

Comment: Note that `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` alone doesn't seem to be enough to get the modules to actually work, at least on Ubuntu Oneiric: I had to set up the `etc/ld.so.conf.d/cuda.conf` file as well.

Comment: I got CUDA & accelerate working on my MacBook, but not the linux box that I originally had the problem with. The example CUDA program http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=90044 fails to de-mangle the string - so basic CUDA functionality is not working (although it does compile and run)

Comment: Can you post an answer so this question is not left unanswered?

Comment: I would love to! But its still not working on my linux box, where the problem occurred. I'll give it another go and see if I can figure it out.

Answer (score 4):

This error usually indicates that configure was not able to find the CUDA library objects. Specifically, you probably have to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in addition to using `--extra-include_dirs` and `--extra-lib-dirs`. Try the following,

```
env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib cabal --extra-include-dirs=/usr/local/cuda/include --extra-lib-dirs=/usr/local/cuda/lib install cuda
```

You didn't specify which system you are using. If you are in a 64-bit Linux system, you may have to use `/usr/local/cuda/lib64` instead of `/usr/local/cuda/lib`.

Comment: Thanks Manuel. I am in fact on a 64-bit linux machine. I tried setting the ENV, and doing "cabal --extra-include-dirs=/usr/local/cuda/include --extra-lib-dirs=/usr/local/cuda/lib64 install cuda" . But I still get the same error msg. All I can figure is that although the CUDA library is in place, its not functional for some reason. Works fine on my MacBook Pro

Comment: The CUDA SDK includes some example programs. One is called `deviceQuery`. It does a basic sanity check to see whether your installation and hardware is working. Did you try that on the Linux box?

Comment: In my case (cuda toolkit and nvidia driver installed from Ubuntu 13.04 packages) it was necessary to add the directory containing `libcuda.so` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` but I didn't need to set the cabal flags.

Comment: @MaciekMakowski Strangely, I also had to reference the location of libcuda.so (/usr/lib/nvidia-304 in my case).  But it only worked when I added that path to the --extra-lib-dirs flag and not the ENV variable.

Answer (score 1):

The answer didn't work for me on Ubuntu 13.10 but the following did (seems to depend strongly on how the nvidia driver was installed, in my case via the nvidia-319 package)

```
env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/nvidia-319 cabal --extra-include-dirs=/usr/local/cuda/include --extra-lib-dirs=/usr/lib/nvidia-319/ install accelerate-cuda
```

of course YMMV and ideally the installer would be modified to look in places where the cuda libraries should be.

Answer (score -1):

To build as libary

> Right Click->Properties->Build->Setting-Build Artifact->Dropdown to choose Shared/Static library

Difference between Shared / Static library

Now to include this library, copy the library to the project you want it and put it in a libs folder at the same level as the src level. Note, I am assuming that you have a src folder.

On this project

> Right Click->Properties->Build->Setting->Libraries->

- in the `-l` area add name of library without the prefix `lib` and without the suffix `.so`
- in the `-L` area add `../libs`, remember its **2 dots** since the current folder is `src`, **not** the root of the project :) YEAH, I tried `./libs` for 1 hours before trying out `../libs`